# How can I convert a Base64 string to binary using Perl

Tags: perl, binary, base64

Is it possible to take a Base64 string and convert it to binary using basic Perl (i.e. just the packages in a standard release, no 3rd party libraries from CPAN)? If so, how?

I came across the module MIME::Base64 which appears to convert from plain text->Base64 and Base64->plain text but I can't seem to find anything to go from Base64 to binary.

-----EDIT-----

It's possible my notion of binary is confused. Essentially. I have a Base64 string passed via an HTML form field. I would like to convert that string into whatever format necessary so as to download that file to the user's browser.

From what I understand. If I first print the correct MIME type headers and then print the raw file data that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it backwards. [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aBase64), like the encoding, only handles bytes. If you have decoded text, you would have to encode it first.

This demonstrates its ability to handle arbitrary bytes:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 encode_base64 );
my $expected = join '', map chr, 0x00..0xFF;
my $base64 = encode_base64($expected);
print($base64);
my $got = decode_base64($base64);
print($got eq $expected ? "ok" : "error", "\n");
```

```
AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4
OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3Bx
cnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn+AgYKDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PkJGSk5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en6ChoqOkpaanqKmq
q6ytrq+wsbKztLW2t7i5uru8vb6/wMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna29zd3t/g4eLj
5OXm5+jp6uvs7e7v8PHy8/T19vf4+fr7/P3+/w==
ok
```

This demonstrates its inability to handle text that hasn't first been encoded into bytes:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
encode_base64("\x{2660}");
print("ok\n");
```

```
Wide character in subroutine entry at a.pl line 2.
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @ikegami! I'm still a little confused. If I had a base64 encoded string (let's call it $zipfile), how would I go about converting $zipfile to binary?

Comment: @Max Hartshorn, "binary" just means "can contain/handle arbitrary bytes". You can't convert to binary, since binary is not a format. Anyway, you simply want `decode_base64($zipfile)`.

Comment: That works! I feel kind of silly now. So essentially decode_base64 decodes a base64 string into whatever its original unencoded byte sequence was. If that sequence was originally a piece of text then it's decoded back into a piece of text. If it was originally a file then it's decoded back into a file. Thanks again.